# Adjacent Numbers are adjacent in the table

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a 10*10 chess table and we have numbers 1-100 in the table. We don't know the number in each grid，but adjacent numbers will also be adjacent in the table.(if two grid have a public edge， we say they are adjacent). Each step you can see one number in the table. How many steps do you need to find arbitrary x in the table

**my attempt to solve this problem:** the numbers in the black grid are both odd or even. So the first step can find the color of number x. Then I have no idea to continue. The only thing I come up with is that if we find a, then a+1,a-1 will be in the up,down,left or right. So we can use at most 20 steps to narrow x in 4 grids. Then we can use another 3 steps to find x. Total is 24. I wonder whether 24 is the optimistic answer or we can find a better algorithm

Comment: What is the source of the problem?

Comment: It's an algorithm question asked by a well-known Internet firm last year.